# C code reshaper

Tags: c, refactoring, code-generation, code-formatting

I am working with Matlab code generator. It is not possible to include code style guidelines. That's why I am looking for a tool to "reshape", rename and reformat the generated code according to my:

- Function banner conventions
- File banner conventions
- Naming conventions
- And so on.

Is there such a tool?

Comment: maybe eclipse editor will do an aouto format the way you like.

Answer (score 1):

There is always good ol' **indent**. http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/

This is a command-line tool, so you could easily include it in your build chain.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse, Netbeans or any other decent IDE have options for code formatting. Maybe you can grab your code from Matlab and work with it in IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/).  It will do some of what you want, but I don't know of any tool that will reformat for naming conventions and such as that could be a complex task.